# What does this JavaScript code return for bar, baz, and biz function calls?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

Learning JavaScript Fundamentals, confused on what the function calls return.
I have an idea of f.bar returns 7 because when the f object is created it gets access to functions of Foo that have the "this" keyword. Also I believe f.baz returns an error because this function is only available locally and does not use the "this" keyword which makes it unavailable outside Foo. f.biz I am confused but I do know the Prototype keyword allows for inheritance of Foo properties.

An explanation for each function call would be awesome, thank you everyone!

```js
var Foo = function(a){

  this.bar = () => {
    return a; 
  }

  var baz = function(){
    return a;
  }

  Foo.prototype = {
    biz: () => {
      return this.bar();
    }
  }

}

var f = new Foo(7);

f.bar();// what does this return?
f.baz(); // what does this return?
f.biz(); // what does this return?
```

Comment: If you want to know the return value just wrap the calls in a `console.log()` -> `console.log(f.bar());`

Comment: If this was provided in a course, throw away the course. There should be no `Foo.prototype =` **inside** `Foo`. It should appear **after** the definition of `Foo`.

Comment: *"an explanation of each function would be awesome"*: this is too broad. It is not clear what needs to be explained. Please focus your question on *one* specific issue you bump into.

Comment: This was a question a friend got in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is now, only the `bar` function will work as intended.

The `baz` function is in a local variable, so it's only accessible *inside* the `Foo` function as `baz` but not as `this.baz` (variables and instance properties (`this.whatever`) are not connected in any way).

The case of `biz` is a bit more complicated. Normally, that's more or less how you'd create a prototype method, but you did it in the wrong place. It should be *outside* the function, because the way it is now, it's:

- reassigned on every call of `new Foo()` (unnecessary)
- assigned only *after* the current instance is created, so it will take effect only on the next instance (also if you used `a` in it (which you shouldn't), you'd find that it always has the `a` of the previous call)

You also don't want to use an arrow function when you want to "let JS set `this`" (arrow functions copy their `this` from where they were defined).

So, to make `biz` work, you have to do this:

```js
var Foo = function(a){

  this.bar = () => {
    return a; 
  }

}

Foo.prototype = {
  biz: function (){
    return this.bar();
  }
}


var f = new Foo(7);

console.log(f.bar());
console.log(f.biz());
```